# Install mongodb on mac os 10.15 for php7

Tags: mongodb, php-7, macos-catalina

I have installed mongodb on my mac Catalina 10.15. I have php7.3 version installed as well. Now, I want to use the mongoClient() class with PHP. I tried `composer require mongodb/mongodb` but it says that the mongodb extension is missing :

```
Using version ^1.5 for mongodb/mongodb
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- mongodb/mongodb 1.5.1 requires ext-mongodb ^1.6 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
- mongodb/mongodb 1.5.0 requires ext-mongodb ^1.6 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
- Installation request for mongodb/mongodb ^1.5 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.5.0, 1.5.1].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
- /etc/php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

So I tried to install the extension for php using [the php doc](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/mongodb.installation.homebrew.php) and I get this error :

```
pear/install/mongodb/php_phongo.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/php_phongo.o
/private/tmp/pear/install/mongodb/php_phongo.c:22:10: fatal error: 'php.h' file not found
#include <php.h>
          ^~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [php_phongo.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Any help ?

Comment: It seems installing php tooling on a mac is difficult.  Which framework do you use to install it?  PECL, Brew?  Did you install autoconf?  On top of all that the PHP driver page has a warning at the top - Warning This extension is deprecated. Instead, the MongoDB extension should be used.  Gads, what are they talking about.  I need a fortune reader to help.

Comment: do check out https://www.php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php though...

Comment: @barrypucker I use the PHP version coming with mac os, and PECL to install mongodb driver for php

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same issue after upgrading to MacOS Catalina

Run these two commands;

1. brew doctor
2. brew link --overwrite php

Answer (score 0):

I also updated the macos to 10.15 catalina and started the setup. As same as error came during installing the **mongodb** driver

### After Resolving my issue I updated the answer by given below steps:

**Step 1:**
Run the command: brew install php71

**Step 2:**
Edit httpd.conf under directory of /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

Add below line

LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/opt/php@7.1/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so

then check there should be no other php7_module enabled.

Also add these lines

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

**Step 3:** Restart apache: sudo apachectl restart

**Step 4:**
If you need to have php@7.1 first in your PATH run:
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.1/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.1/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

For compilers to find php@7.1 you may need to set:
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/php@7.1/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/php@7.1/include"

**Step 5:**
To have launched start php@7.1 now and restart at login:
brew services start php@7.1

**Step 6:**
Open new terminal & check php version & it should be 7.1

**Step 7:**
Then run the command: sudo pecl install MongoDB

& it will install php mongodb driver successfully without any error.
Make sure all step should be followed!!

I did these steps to resolve my MongoDB driver issue for laravel project which not found.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I don't have such path for step 1. No pho directory in Cellar/ any idea where to find this ?

Comment: I updated my answer, I hope it will help macOS user to install PHP MongoDB driver for laravel projects, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed that by installing PHP7.3 using homebrew
here is a post that helped [Install PHP 7.3 + xdebug on MacOS Catalina (with homebrew)](https://medium.com/@romaninsh/install-php-7-2-xdebug-on-macos-high-sierra-with-homebrew-july-2018-d7968fe7e8b8)