# Unable to run MongoDB with Laravel and MacOS Catalina

Tags: laravel, mongodb, macos-catalina

I am attempting to deploy Laravel with MongoDB, using this package:

https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb

I followed these instructiones for installing MongoDB:

https://zellwk.com/blog/install-mongodb/

However, following these instructions did not seem to install the mongo php driver, as Laravel is throwing the error:

```
Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found
```

and checking my php.info, the mongo driver is not listed.

Most of the instructions that I've found for installing the mongo php driver recommend using:

```
sudo pecl install mongodb
```

Unfortunately, being on Catalina, pecl no longer seems to function properly since Apple removed the php header files, so most pecl commands result in an error:

```
fatal error: 'php.h' file not found
```

So what exactly are my options here? What is the correct way to load the mongo drivers into php? Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:
I followed these instructions and was able to fix the php.h error.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59544311/3825421

At that point, I started getting a new error when running pecl:

```
ERROR: failed to mkdir /usr/local/Cellar/php/7.2.5/pecl/20170718
```

I solved this issue by following these instructions:

https://javorszky.co.uk/2018/05/03/getting-xdebug-working-on-php-7-2-and-homebrew/

Although the instructions are for installing xdebug, the issue is the same for mongodb. There is an unused symlink in the directory where pecl is attempting to create a new directory. Remove the symlink and then pecl can create the directory that it needs to.

I then updated the path for mongodb.so in my php.ini, created the ext-mongodb.ini file, and restarted apache. MongoDB now shows up in my php.info. I feel like I probably made this install process needlessly complicated by doing something wrong, but maybe someone else will find my experience helpful.